# Delimiters with bcp import

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to import bulk data from text files. The statement that i use is below:

```
DECLARE @s as varchar(300)

SET @s='bcp [hc]..[QRYM_COMPANIES] in ' + char(34) + 'C:\SQL Files\health canada allfiles\comp.txt' + char(34) + ' -C ACP -c -t \", -r\n -e' + char(34) + 'C:\SQL Files\health canada allfiles\err\comp.err.txt' + char(34) + ' -b250 -m50 -SServer -Usa -P' + char(34) + 'mypassword' + char(34) + ' -h' + char(34) + 'TABLOCK' + char(34) 


PRINT @s

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @s
```

Now, normally I would have put -t, but my data contains commas in some of the data fields which results in the data being shifted. When I try to use -t \"  I get the error "String data, right truncation", so that is why I am having to use the combination of -t ,\"

The problem here is that I get quotations in my transferred data. Below is a sample row of my data:

```
"20042","NSL95","4797","NU SKIN INTERNATIONAL, INC.","DIN OWNER","Y","N","N","N","","75 WEST CENTER STREET","PROVO","UTAH","UNITED STATES","84601",""
```

The table description is below. To avoid the "string truncation error" i have added a 1 to the left field size.

**Can someone help me fix this problem?**

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [health_canada].[dbo].[QRYM_COMPANIES] (

DRUG_CODE   VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, --NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL,

MFR_CODE        VARCHAR(15),

COMPANY_CODE        VARCHAR(16), --NUMERIC(6),

COMPANY_NAME        VARCHAR(180),

COMPANY_TYPE        VARCHAR(140),

ADDRESS_MAILING_FLAG        VARCHAR(11),

ADDRESS_BILLING_FLAG        VARCHAR(11),

ADDRESS_NOTIFICATION_FLAG       VARCHAR(11),

ADDRESS_OTHER       VARCHAR(11),

SUITE_NUMERIC       VARCHAR(120),

STREET_NAME         VARCHAR(180),

CITY_NAME       VARCHAR(160),

PROVINCE        VARCHAR(140),

COUNTRY         VARCHAR(140),

POSTAL_CODE         VARCHAR(120),

POST_OFFICE_BOX         VARCHAR(115)

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is it possible for your data to have a double quote character within it? If so how is it encoded?

Comment: Also were you aware that there is a BULK INSERT T-SQL command that does much the same thing. However Microsoft do state in the documentation for it that "Comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server bulk-import operations". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I have normally found it easier to do these kind of imports by writing my own console application in something like C#.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use a format file with your bcp call. It is easy to configure, and you can fine tune it for your file. Just add -f and the path to use it: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F7rw.png)

**Steps**

- Add the format file to the disk (make sure that the SQL server can reach the path).
- Update paths in query.
- Run query.

**I used this file:**
[image]

**This code imported your example data without quotations with the format file:**

```
DECLARE @importTable VARCHAR(128) = 'hc.dbo.QRYM_COMPANIES';
DECLARE @importPath VARCHAR(8000) = '\\YOURPATH\comp.txt';
DECLARE @formatFilePath VARCHAR(8000) = '\\YOURPATH\formatFile.txt';
DECLARE @separator VARCHAR(10) = '';

DECLARE @export VARCHAR(8000) = 'bcp "' + @importTable + '" in "' + @importPath + '" -T -f "' + @formatFilePath + '" -C RAW -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;

PRINT(@export)
EXEC xp_cmdshell @export
```

**Output:**

[image]

**SELECT * FROM hc.dbo.QRYM_COMPANIES:**

[image]

**Add this format file to your disk:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD> 
  <FIELD ID="0" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="18" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="15" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="16" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="180" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="140" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="120" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="180" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="160" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="140" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="140" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' MAX_LENGTH="120" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="115" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="DRUG_CODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="MFR_CODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="COMPANY_CODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="COMPANY_NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="COMPANY_TYPE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="ADDRESS_MAILING_FLAG" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="ADDRESS_BILLING_FLAG" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="ADDRESS_NOTIFICATION_FLAG" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="ADDRESS_OTHER" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="SUITE_NUMERIC" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="STREET_NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="CITY_NAME" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="PROVINCE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="COUNTRY" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="POSTAL_CODE" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="POST_OFFICE_BOX" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**You can auto generate new format files with bcp if you need it for other files/tables (no need to do this now if the format file works)**

**Important:** 
After format file export:

- Replace: `TERMINATOR="\&quot;,"` to `TERMINATOR='","'`
- Replace: `TERMINATOR="\r\n"` to `TERMINATOR='"\r\n'`*
- Add to `<record>` (will remove first quotation): `<FIELD ID="0" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>`

**Auto generate query:**

```
DECLARE @importTable VARCHAR(128) = 'hc.dbo.QRYM_COMPANIES';
DECLARE @formatFilePath VARCHAR(8000) = '\\YourFilePath\formatFile.txt';
DECLARE @bcpCall VARCHAR(8000);

SET @bcpCall = 'bcp "' + @importTable + '" format nul -c -t", -x -f "' + @formatFilePath + '" -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;

PRINT @bcpCall 

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpCall
```

Comment: The problem is that I receive the files like that. It is probably more practical for me to do a search and replace and use a different delimiter, but I would rather avoid doing that and deal with the original file as is. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @user2246935: If you use the format file, it will remove the quotations for you with the TERMINATOR='","' and the TERMINATOR='"\r\n'. I can give you an example of a bcp command with the format file if it would help?

Comment: @user2246935: I just testet a Import based on your example with the  quotations. It worked fine, I will update my answer to a more step by step.

Comment: @user2246935: I have updated my answer to be more detailed. I have provided an example of how to use bcp with the format file, and updated the auto generated format file for you, so you can use it without altering it.

Comment: Hi Jarle, Thank you very much. Yes it works beautifully. Wow. I really appreciate you taking the time to try it out.

Comment: @user2246935: That is great, I am glad it worked out. I would appreciate if you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.